What is strategy?
This is a word that is commonly used as a buzz-word to describe a wide range of things - it's something that has always bothered me.
My personal view on 'strategy' is: at the most abstract level, a strategy exists as a thesis upon which one can fullfil the goal of winning in a given endeavour.
For example: in business, a strategy is a thesis that is an argument that asserts a number of premises, which are substantive choices [composed of form and matter] that a company will make, that are asserted to be true, that ultimately fit together to infer a conclusion of the company achieving its winning aspiration.
E.g. one of those premises will assert how the company creates competitive advantage.
What are your thoughts?

You may look up the meaning of the term "strategy" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy It is similar to your proposal. - But please note that your question does not fall under the aim of this Q&A pages about philosophy.

I’m voting to close this question because the site, per its guidelines, shuns "What are your thoughts" questions in lieu of brief, fact-based Q&A questions about and from canonical philosophical literature.

Isn't the purpose of this board to inspire discussion and debate? With all due respect, if Wikipedia was the source of truth for everything and anything, this thread wouldn't have been created.

E.g. one of those premises will assert how the company creates competitive advantage.. Why only one? Why do so many questions assume there must be a single correct answer?

Without a competitive advantage, you will have no differentiation in how to win - what happens then? Even a giant commoditiser has some form of advantange e.g. distribution and marketing differentiation. For others- You get lost in the pack of many others, on top of that, your way of winning must be easily replicable if you don't have an advantage that exists.
The other premises seek to provide evidence of how to win outside of just the thesis for advantage. E.g. what are the capabilities to enable this advantage?

In strategy you have quite possibly an infinite amount of choices you could make, the goal is to have one answer: the best choice.

But you said "one premise". The best choice may combine several considerations.

[Isn't the purpose of this board to inspire discussion and debate?] No, it's not.  See https://stackexchange.com/tour for an introduction to the purpose and format of SE. "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. [...] Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

@JD, FYI, this reason to close is already stated as part of the first reason under site-specific reasons.

Yes- one premise - exists after you have boiled it down. If you can't boil it down you haven't achieved its essence. Such a premise will represent the form - the premise is not there to prescribe the matter.

I'm not sure that the term 'strategy' gets the full philosophical treatment. Some topics like the philosophy of mathematics receive mountains of coverage, and other topics such as design or engineering have far less literature containing philosophical analysis. Let's do our best.
In a nutshell, strategy is simply a plan to achieve a goal. With this sense, in philosophy, it is often the nature of teleology that is discussed and studied. Since the Aristotelian four causes implicitly considers teleological thinking with the efficient cause, cause and effect are therefore important in strategic thinking.
But the original definition offered is far too broad. For instance, it's common to observe a distinction between tactics and strategy (asana.com). From the article:

While strategy is the action plan that takes you where you want to go, the tactics are the individual steps and actions that will get you there.

The article also mentions that this distinction was held by Sun Tzu in his Art of War. Thus military strategy is one avenue of studying what strategy is. First to mind are books like Clausewitz's On War and Warfighting by CMC Krulak. Military strategy books by Keegan are also well known.
Your definition of business strategy is deficient according to Richard Rumelt per his Good Strategy, Bad Strategy (GB). In his work, one key defining concept for strategy is the nature of the plan. It must be comprehensive across multiple domains. Everyone has a plan or a pep speech in business, but there are certain qualities of successful business strategy that he covers. Ideas like 'focus' and 'business advantage' are offered and defined among others. Problem-solving strategies is another genre of literature. How to Solve It by Pólya is one that is famous in math education.
Poking around various resources like the SEP, the IEP, and Google Books, I did come across a few works that sound like the philosophy of strategy, but nothing like a full conceptual analysis seems to come up. There's a book Theory of Strategy by a Colin Gray (GB) that looks at first glance to be a philosophical analysis, but the fine print contains military terminology. Other areas of publication that might be of interest to you is AI such as AI: A Modern Approach by Russell and Norvig, which contains an entire section on planning, game theory, and instrumental rationalism (SEP).
Looks like reference requests for the philosophy of strategy are non-existent because there's been no real effort to investigate the topic in a philosophically rigorous way! Someone's PhD thesis waiting to happen.

Whilst a plan is imperative in enabling a strategy to come into fruition, I don't believe a plan resolves the question of - what is strategy? Moreover, from what I've observed in my discipline of building products, there is an over-investment in having well co-ordinated and articulated plans but an disproportionate lack of investment into defining a coherent and well articulated strategy that precedes the existence of a plan. Thanks for the response!

The issue with things like Art of War is, it focuses on winning from a brutality perspective - does 'winning' have to be brute force? Does it have to be winner takes all in a defined territory? I don't believe so. We have various types of tech companies: Amazon, Apple, Meta and so on. All with distinctive capabilities and offers - I believe what re-inforces all of this together is not planning, but strategy. Having a strategy that articulates what the company will, and will not invest in which over-time defines the meaning and existence of the company.

E.g. Apple set out to be a computer company - overtime its existence and definition in the world has come to mean to enable customers of all kinds [consumers or business] to fullfill [the final cause of the iPhone for example] of being able to do what they do best {e/g/ what theyre passionate about}, through products that enable the best possible subject experience, that is deemed objective from the view of the market.

Well, certainly, in the simplest sense, the first def'n of strategy I offered is too simple, but that it is a plan of sorts begins the process of helping to determine additional necessary and sufficient conditions to make a plan a strategy. Enter the WP article which introduces the additional element of uncertainty. Rumelt adds comprehensiveness across domains as a major element. As for winning in military strategy, sometimes outsmarting and out-organizing are sub-strategies. There's a motto in one part of the US Army...

Amateurs win with combat tactics, professionals win with logistics. And goals are highly normative.

"make a plan a strategy." Is your implication that a plan makes a strategy and not the other way around? I would have to disagree. The way I view this is, you'd be trying to make something concrete into the abstract - to solve an abstract problem - you could... but is this going to give you the 'best' strategy [afterall that's what we want]? I would say no. I believe that, it is through the correct abstract framing of the abstract question to be solved, does the right concrete plan come into existence that achieves the outcomes we seek to achieve - be it goals, ambitions etc.

@surbjitsingh You seem interesting in having genuinely productive discourse about strategy. I'll start up a chatroom later tonight, invite you, and we can have an extended conversation about it.

@J D sounds good. btw I'm by no means claiming to be a philosophy expert - I'm an amateur lol
